# TFS 2012 - Scheduled Backups Failing

Tags: tfs, database-backups

I'm trying to setup Nightly Backups for my TFS 2012.4 development box going off to another server, but it's failing.

The server is has SQL Express and TFS Express on it, trying to send the backups over to a network path on another share.

When going through the Wizard it will successfully pass all of the Readiness Checks, including permissions. It will fail when it tries to run the backup job for the first time under Confirming Permissions.

Error is:

> TF401002: The SQL Server Database Engine failed to save the database
>   backup to path \[share]\c$\TFSBackup. Please grant SQL service
>   account read/write access to that folder.

I've tried adding "Everyone" with full control to the folder on the backup server, but it still fails with the same error.

Added the full log to http://pastebin.com/80PrYXqx

Comment: did the answer below solve your issue?  Can you mark it as accepted if it did, or explain if it didn't?

Answer (score 6):

This may be a problem with using the administrative share path of c$. I suggest you go to your [share] server and make the TFSBackup folder a [shared folder](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770880.aspx), and give your share the appropriate permissions.

Then you can change this:

> \\[share]\c$\TFSBackup

To something like this(depending on what you name your share):

> \\[share]\TFSBackup$

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post, but just incase anyone else has issues. I had the same issue configuring backups.  The following resolved it for me:

1) Open up "Services" and note the "Log On As" user for "Sql Server" and "Sql Server Agent"

2) On the folder that your backups are being saved to, go to Properties -> Security -> Edit

3) Add the users from #1, and check "Full Control", Save